# How to Convert labelme json data to Pascal VOC format using labelme2voc.py

Tags: json, object-detection, single-shot-detector, labelme

I have annotated images in label-me and the annotation is saved in .json file. I am trying to train a SSD object dictation model and I need data in Pascal VOC format. Label me has a file named labelme2voc.py I tried multiple time and failed each time the documentation regarding this is also very poor. Does anyone know how to convert json to Pascal VOC using these? any-other way would also be appreciated. I have 4 classes but each image conations upwards of 50 annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download [labelme2voc.py](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/blob/main/examples/instance_segmentation/labelme2voc.py) file and save to your computer (I saved inside the dataset folder).

Then you need to create a "labels" file containing the label names you used, that needs to be similar to the [one provided by labelme](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/blob/main/examples/instance_segmentation/labels.txt). You can also save this file inside the dataset folder.

Then you're gonna run `python3 labelme2voc.py data_annotaded data_dataset_voc --labels labels.txt`

You're gonne change `data_annotaded` by the path of the data you annotated (where the annotated json is located). And you're gonna change `data_dataset_voc` by any name you wish your output folder will be called.

In my case I have the following folder structure:

```
├── labelme2voc.py 
├── labels.txt 
├── test_labelme 
│   ├── 1.json
│   ├── 1.png
..........
│   ├── 9.json
│   └── 9.png
└── train_labelme
    ├── 1.json
    ├── 1.png
    ......
    ├── 3.json
    └── 3.png
```

And I'm calling `python3 labelme2voc.py train_labelme train_labelme/train_voc --labels labels.txt` to generate the annotation.